# Can 'Azure Event Hub' check event schema prior to ingestion - can it 'pre-filter' data coming in?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

If a device or an application sends an event with an invalid JSON schema, is it possible to stop this coming into an event hub?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something on the Event Hubs side that will check if your schema is not the same as some schema you need, then no.

Comment: can this be achieved using something else in the middle between the device and Event Hub?

Comment: It can be implemented on the gateway. Gateway can be something like the "server" installed on the Raspberry Pi. Basically, your devices send the information to the gateway, it checks that and send it further. Or you can use Stream Analytics service and implement some logic, but SA will just fail the message and not stop it.

Comment: what we are trying to achieve is that when messages come into an Event Hub if they do not conform to a schema we want those messages to go on to a different Event Hub which will hold bad schema messages. So that we know that our downstream processing never breaks. We are planning to use SAS for storing incoming stream of messages from Event Hub into an Azure SQL DB. How can we achieve this? We do not have control over the device/application that generates the events.

Comment: Ah! Got the idea. Then, maybe, it makes sense to consider to use Azure Service Bus Queue, that have the dead-lettering queue for poisoned messages that can't be processed for some reason? https://www.dougv.com/2015/07/handling-poison-messages-in-an-azure-service-bus-queue/ It adds a software component, but looks like a viable solution in your case. Basically - you have device sending msgs to the SB Queue, some lightweight worker processing the messages and their schema and sending them further if OK and dead-lettering for a future inspection into the subqueue.

Comment: But Service Bus Queues are based on a competing consumer model so not scalable as Events Hubs. We trying to avoid Queues and Topics.

Comment: Makes sense. Then, that leaves me with the proposal of implementing receiver for Event Hub which will inspect the messages and pass the correct messages further. Device => Event Hub => Web Site/Cloud Service => Event Hub => Stream Analytics. Chaining Event Hubs is the popular approach.